# Why is $\int_0^\infty 1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}dt=X(\omega)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a non-negative continuous random variable (i.e. $P(X<0)=0$).

Why is it that under the Lebesgue integration:

$$\int_0^\infty 1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}dt=X(\omega).$$

My approach to understand this equality was to re-write LHS as a full-fledged Lebesgue integration:

$$\int_0^\infty 1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}dt=\int_\mathbb{R}1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}1_{[0,\infty)}d\lambda(t).$$

But I don't understand how this leads to the actual random variable $X(\omega)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X(\omega) > 0$, your integral is actually just

$$\int_0^{X(\omega)} 1\,dt$$

since you are integrating over those $t$ that are less than $X(\omega)$. Said another way, $1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}(t) = 1_{[0, X(\omega)]}(t)$ which you can easily verify by picking a $t$ less than $X(\omega)$ and a $t$ greater than $X(\omega)$.

Comment: I agree with what you said. But how do you justify putting $X(w)$  as the upper limit of the integral?

Comment: The logic is in the rest of my explanation. You're integrating $1$ over $[0, X(\omega)]$.

Comment: thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

The integrand $1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}$ must be looked at as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with argument $t$.

It is prescribed by $t\mapsto1$ if $t<X(\omega)$ and $t\mapsto0$ otherwise, so actually: $$1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}=1_{(-\infty,X(\omega))}(t)$$

This leads for positive $X(\omega)$ to: $$\int_0^\infty 1_{\{X(\omega)>t\}}dt=\int_0^{\infty}1_{(-\infty,X(\omega))}(t)dt=\int_0^{X(\omega)}dt=[t]^{X(\omega)}_0=X(\omega)$$

Comment: In your second line, how do you go from 2nd to 3rd?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{(-\infty,X(\omega))}(t)dt=\int1_{\left(0,\infty\right)}\left(t\right)1_{(-\infty,X(\omega))}(t)=\int1_{(0,X(\omega))}(t)=\int_{0}^{X(\omega)}dt$

Comment: thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

For any nonnegative value $z$,
$$
\int_0^\infty 1_{\{t:z>t\}}dt=\int_0^z\;dt = z.
$$
This has nothing to do with random variables.  When you have done this, note that it holds in particular when $z = X(\omega)$, provided $X(\omega) \ge 0$.

Comment: +1 for the „this has nothing to do with random variables“

Comment: thanks for the response!